# sql database prefixes

Tags: php, mysql

When I create a database on my hostgator webserver, it prepends a database prefix to the database name. for instance if I do

```
CREATE DATABASE 'dbname'
```

it makes a db called `myname_dbname`

My question is, is there a way I can have my PHP get the db prefix so that I can add it into my configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

The prefix value is usually your `login` name. On shell you can find it using

```
echo $LOGNAME
```

In PHP you can use [**getenv**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) as:

```
$DB_prefix = getenv('LOGNAME');
```

Comment: Ah, nice. Didn't know that was often the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hard code the prefix? Would that be such a bad thing? Or set up your config to detect the hosting environment and add the prefix only in this situation.

I'd say you could use `DESCRIBE` to get information about the Db, but I am guessing it is s shared host and your ability to use statements like `DESCRIBE` might be limited.

Comment: well basically the code I'm writing is for distribution and I want other people to be able to install it as well. The installation creates the db, tables, and writes the data out to a config files.